# Composer / drupal commands generate errors. What is wrong w/ my setup?

Tags: drupal, command-line, module, composer-php

From drupal installed directory I Generated a fresh new install of drupal 8.

I then generated a new module w/ the drupal console

```
drupal generate:module
Enter the new module name:

 > broucher
 Enter the module machine name [broucher]:
 > 
 Enter the module Path [modules/custom]:
 > 
 Enter module description [My Awesome Module]:
 > Brochure Entiy Module
 Enter package name [Custom]:
 > 
 Enter Drupal Core version [8.x]:
 > 
 Do you want to generate a .module file? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > 
 Define module as feature (yes/no) [no]:
 > 
 Do you want to add a composer.json file to your module? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > 
 Would you like to add module dependencies? (yes/no) [no]:
 > 
 Do you want to generate a unit test class? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > 
 Do you want to generate a themeable template? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >   
 Do you want proceed with the operation? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > 
Generated or updated files
 Generation path: /Users/mike/websites/content-entity-example-VI
 1 - /modules/custom/broucher/broucher.info.yml
 2 - /modules/custom/broucher/broucher.module
 3 - /modules/custom/broucher/composer.json
 4 - /modules/custom/broucher/tests/src/Functional/LoadTest.php
 5 - /modules/custom/broucher/broucher.module
 6 - /modules/custom/broucher/templates/broucher.html.twig                                                                                                                   
 Generated lines: "101"
```

I then ran a update on the module:

```
drupal module:update brochure --composer
```

A long set of error messages then display (can append if considered important)

Final error seems to be: 
[

```
RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                            
    Source directory /Users/mike/websites/content-entity-example-VI/vendor/drupal/coder has uncommitted changes.
```

Subsequent executions of ‘drupal’ get’s error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/mike/websites/content-entity-example-VI/vendor/composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/mike/websites/content-entity-example-VI/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

If I do a composer update running ‘drupal’ on the command line it appears to be ready to run again.

I’ve been beating on this for several hours; any help would be appreciated.